# How do I get my 5 month old to take longer naps?

Tags: infant, sleep-training, naps

My daughter is 5 months old and is an amazing night sleeper who is able to settle herself to sleep during the night she goes to bed at 8 and will not wake until 430-5 o clock for a feed then wakes up at about 730. What I would like advice on is getting her to sleep longer during the day. She will show signs of being tired yawning rubbing eyes  multiple times during the day but when I put her down she will either take forever to settle or will sleep for no longer than 45 mins at a time. I would like to know how to get her to sleep for longer periods of time . I’m afraid this might be because she is overtired because she couldn’t get into a deeper sleep. Help please any tips on how to improve her napping habits would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember my both kids napped for 15 minutes and that was it! They were both constantly tired and needed longer naps. To help them I used the Hold WIth Love method from "How to teach a baby to fall asleep alone" guide by Susan Urban and it was like a miracle! it took me 4 days with my daughter and 3 days with my son to make them nap longer.

Answer (score 1):

If she normally sleeps about 45 minutes, have a chair in the hallway outside his bedroom door and at about 15 minutes before she wakes up sit there and read a book or knit and wait and listen. The minute your little one starts to make any kind of sound like she's waking up, rush in there and pat her, rub her, rock her, do whatever you need to do to get her to go back to sleep. If you will have caught her before she's fully awake, she will go back to sleep and then finish her nap and if you do this for a week or two you'll find she'll get in the habit of taking a longer nap and that will become part of her daily routine. This advice is from Elizabeth Pantley, author of "The No-Cry Sleep Solution". You can find her videos and tips from other experts on [baby sleep here](https://www.kidsinthehouse.com/baby/sleep).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get my 5 month old to take longer naps?

The trick here is to *make sure they are as active as possible while they are awake*.  Make sure they are always moving and playing in a safe but physical way.  Such things as *the walker game, the jumpy chair, etc.* to **keep your child engaged and moving around** as much as possible.

This will earn you longer naps.